# Is it good practice to add database connection object to the process.env global in node.js?

Tags: node.js, process, module, redis

We *already* use **node**'s `process.env` **Global Object** to store/access [**environment variables**](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-environment-variables) but can we also attach other objects that need to be accessible across several files/modules ?

A **concrete example**: 
Imagine you are connecting to a Datastore *e.g*. **Redis**<sup>1</sup> and you are *modularising* your app so that each module would open its own connection to Redis.

Would it make sense to use the following:

```
process.env.redisClient = || process.env.redisClient || require('redis').createClient()
// use the shared/global connection for your needs:
process.env.redisClient.set('Hello', 'World');
process.env.redisClient.get('Hello', function(err, reply) {
 console.log('Hello ' + reply);
});
```

I *realise* this question can be *perceived* as "*subjective*" or "opinion-based", but I'm not asking for anyone's *opinion*; I want to know if there are people with ***specific experience*** of cases where adding an object to `process.env` will "*break production*" or have another *adverse effect*.

<sup>1</sup> its the same for any db where the **number of connections** should be ***minimised*** so applies to MySQL, PostgeSQL, MongoDB etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this does not work. 
We ***cannot*** attach an object or function to node's `process.env` Global object because all entries added to `process.env` are type-cast to **String**.

If you're interested in how we ended up solving this problem see: https://github.com/nelsonic/redis-connection

Comment: Cool module, and funny intro to Redis from dwyl - liked both :)

Comment: Thanks @ItamarHaber :) we Love RedisCloud BTW!